# Reordering heatmap from seaborn using column info from additional text file

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I wrote a python script to read in a distance matrix that was provided via a CSV text file. This distance matrix shows the difference between different animal species, and I'm trying to sort them in different ways(diet, family, genus, etc.) using data from another CSV file that just has one row of ordering information. Code used is here:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp

dietCols = pd.read_csv("label_diet.txt", header=None)
df = pd.read_csv("distance_matrix.txt", header=None)

ax = sns.heatmap(df)
fig = ax.get_figure()
fig.savefig("fig1.png")
mp.clf()

dfDiet = pd.read_csv("distance_matrix.txt", header=None, names=dietCols)

ax2 = sns.heatmap(dfDiet, linewidths=0)
fig2 = ax2.get_figure()
fig2.savefig("fig2.png")
mp.clf()
```

When plotting the distance matrix, the original graph looks like this:

[image: original heatmap without issues]

However, when the additional naming information is read from the text file, the graph produced only has one column and looks like this:

[image: heatmap with attempted column orderings]

You can see the matrix data is being used as row labeling, and I'm not sure why that would be. Some of the rows provided have no values so they're listed as "NaN", so I'm not sure if that would be causing a problem. Is there any easy way to order this distance matrix using an exterior file? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the content of your `DietCols` dataframe. Is it the same length as the matrix (115?) and in the same order?

Comment: @joshuabox the DietCols dataframe is the same length as the matrix but is just one column of data, and yes it is in the same order.